# angularjs random password generator at least one upper, lower, number and special character

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, random

How can I make this random password generator to generate at least one of the components?
Currently, it happens that a number is not included in the generated password, or any of other types is left out. How to make it to generate at least of of the types?

```
        $scope.passwordLength = 12;
        $scope.addUpper       = true;
        $scope.addNumbers     = true;
        $scope.addSymbols     = true;

        $scope.createPassword = function(){
            var lowerCharacters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
            var upperCharacters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];
            var numbers = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
            var symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '\'', '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[', '\\', ']', '^', '_', '`', '{', '|', '}', '~'];
            var finalCharacters = lowerCharacters;
            if($scope.addUpper){
                finalCharacters = finalCharacters.concat(upperCharacters);
            }
            if($scope.addNumbers){
                finalCharacters = finalCharacters.concat(numbers);
            }
            if($scope.addSymbols){
                finalCharacters = finalCharacters.concat(symbols);
            }
            var passwordArray = [];
            for (var i = 1; i < $scope.passwordLength; i++) {
                passwordArray.push(finalCharacters[Math.floor(Math.random() * finalCharacters.length)]);
            };
            $scope.password = passwordArray.join("");
        };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are doing is creating array of all possible characters (`finalCharacters`) and taking randomly 12 characters of it.

What you need to do is to take at least one random character from each needed array (`upperCharacters`, `numbers`, `symbols`) and shuffle it.

Algorithm example:

- generating number of lowerCharacters, number of upperCharacters, number of numbers and number of symbols (i.e. 3 lower, 3 upper, 3 numbers, 3 symbols)
- push proper number of random characters from each array (`lowerCharacters`, `upperCharacters`, ...) into array (i.e. `passwordArray`)
- shuffle `passwordArray`
- join `passwordArray`

First step may be:

- `noOfLowerCharacters = 0`, `noOfUpperCharacters = 0`, `noOfUpperCharacters = 0`
- count number of needed types (`1`, `2` or `3`). Store it in variable `noOfneededTypes`.
- take random number from range from `1` to (`passwordLength` - `noOfneededTypes`). Store it in variable `noOfLowerCharacters`.
- create `usedTypeCounter`. Set value to `1`
- if `addUpper` then take random number from range from `1` to (`passwordLength` - `noOfneededTypes` + `usedTypeCounter` - `noOfLowerCharacters`). Store it in variable `noOfUpperCharacters`. Increase `usedTypeCounter`
- if `addNumbers` then take random number from range from `1` to (`passwordLength` - `noOfneededTypes` + `usedTypeCounter` - `noOfLowerCharacters` - `noOfUpperCharacters`). Store it in variable `noOfNumbers`.
- if `addSymbols` then `noOfSymbols` = `passwordLength` - `noOfLowerCharacters` - `noOfUpperCharacters` - `noOfNumbers`

Example of implementation:

```
  $scope.passwordLength = 12;
  $scope.addUpper = true;
  $scope.addNumbers = true;
  $scope.addSymbols = true;

  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

  // shuffle function taken from http://stackoverflow.com/a/12646864/4989081
  function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      var temp = array[i];
      array[i] = array[j];
      array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
  }

  $scope.createPassword = function() {
    var lowerCharacters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
    var upperCharacters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];
    var numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
    var symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '\'', '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[', '\\', ']', '^', '_', '`', '{', '|', '}', '~'];

var noOfLowerCharacters = 0,
  noOfUpperCharacters = 0,
  noOfNumbers = 0,
  noOfSymbols = 0;

var noOfneededTypes = $scope.addUpper + $scope.addNumbers + $scope.addSymbols;

var noOfLowerCharacters = getRandomInt(1, $scope.passwordLength - noOfneededTypes);

var usedTypeCounter = 1;

if ($scope.addUpper) {
  noOfUpperCharacters = getRandomInt(1, $scope.passwordLength - noOfneededTypes + usedTypeCounter - noOfLowerCharacters);
  usedTypeCounter++;
}

if ($scope.addNumbers) {
  noOfNumbers = getRandomInt(1, $scope.passwordLength - noOfneededTypes + usedTypeCounter - noOfLowerCharacters - noOfUpperCharacters);
  usedTypeCounter++;
}

if ($scope.addSymbols) {
  noOfSymbols = $scope.passwordLength - noOfLowerCharacters - noOfUpperCharacters - noOfNumbers;
}

var passwordArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < noOfLowerCharacters; i++) {
  passwordArray.push(lowerCharacters[getRandomInt(1, lowerCharacters.length - 1)]);
}

for (var i = 0; i < noOfUpperCharacters; i++) {
  passwordArray.push(upperCharacters[getRandomInt(1, upperCharacters.length - 1)]);
}

for (var i = 0; i < noOfNumbers; i++) {
  passwordArray.push(numbers[getRandomInt(1, numbers.length - 1)]);
}

for (var i = 0; i < noOfSymbols; i++) {
  passwordArray.push(symbols[getRandomInt(1, symbols.length - 1)]);
}

passwordArray = shuffleArray(passwordArray);

return passwordArray.join("");
};

$scope.password = $scope.createPassword();
```

See working: http://jsfiddle.net/cmoqkkw8/

Comment: yeah that is it, could you please suggest an answer? thanks

Comment: Implementation added. See jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 2):

You can also create random passwords until one of them match your criteria:

```
function randomPass (length, addUpper, addSymbols, addNums) {
    var lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var upper = addUpper ? lower.toUpperCase() : "";
    var nums = addNums ? "0123456789" : "";
    var symbols = addSymbols ? "!#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~" : "";

    var all = lower + upper + nums + symbols;
    while (true) {
        var pass = "";
        for (var i=0; i<length; i++) {
            pass += all[Math.random() * all.length | 0];
        }

        // criteria:
        if (!/[a-z]/.test(pass)) continue; // lowercase is a must
        if (addUpper && !/[A-Z]/.test(pass)) continue; // check uppercase
        if (addSymbols && !/\W/.test(pass)) continue; // check symbols
        if (addNums && !/\d/.test(pass)) continue; // check nums

        return pass; // all good
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something similar is already done at open source JS util here - may help others

[passutil.js](https://github.com/fromdev/tools/blob/master/javascripts/passutil.js)

It is being used on this [site](http://tools.fromdev.com/secure-password-generator.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use this library https://github.com/fent/randexp.js

With this answer [regex to allow atleast one special character, one uppercase, one lowercase(in any order)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557441/regex-to-allow-atleast-one-special-character-one-uppercase-one-lowercasein-an)